Geometry Nodes grow
Is it possible to make this thing grow along the curve?
like a vine



Just trim the curve before resampling.
Use the current frame as factor for the length.

In the picture:

"Total_Frames" is a "Value" node, I set the duration of the animation there
The value in the "Divide" node is #frame (a driver that gets the current frame number)

Basically: trim_factor = current_frame / total_frames
(Alternatively, instead of using a frame driver, you can use a "simulation zone" node)


It worked!! thank you so much!! :D
